# Как задать ширину столбца в pandas автоматически по ширине содержимого?

Tags: python, pandas

Как задать ширину столбца в pandas автоматом по ширине выводимых символов?
Символов много, а название колонки узкое...текст "съедается"
Столбец experience
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пыталась так:

```
d = {"experience":[],
     "loss/learn": [],
     "acc/learn": [], 
     "loss/valid": [],
     "acc/valid": [],
     "loss/test": [],
     "acc/test": []
    }
df3 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df3.style.set_properties(subset=['experience'], **{'width': '500px'})
df3
```

Не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 120)
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
```