# Как задать ширину столбцов в pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel

Как сделать автоматическую настройку ширины столбцов или хотя бы задать фиксированную ширину в `pandas`?

**Что я пробовала:**

Вариант [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031532/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-pandas-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE):

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 120)
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
```

**не помогло.**

Фрагмент кода из [статьи](https://habr.com/ru/post/521894/):

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

**не помогло.**

Код с [данного ответа](https://overcoder.net/q/195003/%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-excel-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E#2802897).

Но очень громоздкий и у меня выдаёт ошибку:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

В строке `header = df[[i]].astype(str).columns.values`.

И как установить размер шрифта и сам шрифт для всех столбцов с заголовками? Вот как я устанавливаю размер шрифта и центрирование для столбцов:

```
df1 = df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'center')])])
df1.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center', 'font-size': '20pt'})
```

Но для заголовков это не применяется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите как это сделано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/5741205)

Comment: Вы где эту ширину хотите выставить, при выводе куда-то или при экспорте в эксель или где вообще?

Comment: Вы можете ответить на вопрос - где вы эту ширину смотрите, каким образом? Выводите на экран, экспортируете в эксель? Потому что это совсем разные истории вообще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-auto-adjust-the-width-of-excel-columns-with-pandas-excelwriter-60cee36e175e) статью посмотрите, должно помочь. Вот текст оттуда:

## Как автоматически настроить ширину столбцов Excel с помощью Pandas ExcelWriter

Как автоматически настроить ширину столбцов Excel с помощью Pandas ExcelWriter
Динамическая настройка ширины имен столбцов Excel при использовании pandas.ExcelWriter и Python

Одна из самых неприятных вещей, с которой вам, возможно, придется иметь дело, - это создание файла Excel с использованием Python, который содержит множество столбцов, которые вы не можете прочитать из-за небольшой ширины столбцов. В идеале вы должны предоставлять читаемые электронные таблицы, в которых все столбцы правильно отформатированы, чтобы их можно было читать.
В этой статье мы собираемся изучить быстрые и простые способы использования
Динамическая настройка ширины всех столбцов в зависимости от длины имени столбца
Настройка определенного столбца по его имени
Настройка определенного столбца с помощью его индекса
Наконец, мы также обсудим, как исправить одну распространенную проблему, которая может возникнуть при вызове `set_column` метода ( `AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_column'`).
Если так, давайте создадим панд DataFrame , которые будут ссылаться в наших примерах, чтобы продемонстрировать действия , которые мы намерены обсудить в этой статье.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
  np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), 
  columns=column_names
)

print(df)

#    column_a  column_b  this_is_a_long_column_name  this_is_another_long_column_name
# 0        91         2                           8                                39
# 1        81        56                           9                                62
# 2        94        82                          36                                34
# 3        54        28                          92                                29
# 4        20        21                          72                                16
# 5        63        71                           8                                63
# 6        64        69                          23                                56
# 7        29        27                          97                                88
# 8         9        83                          38                                36
# 9        83        64                          72                                60
```

Теперь давайте попробуем записать pandas DataFrame, который мы только что создали, в csv-файл, используя `ExcelWriter`, как показано ниже (обратите внимание, что если приведенный ниже фрагмент не работает, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named openpyxl. Все, что вам нужно сделать, это установить библиотеку, запустив` pip install openpyxl`):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file.xlsx') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_analysis', index=False, na_rep='NaN')
writer.save()
```

Написание `pandas DataFrame` в электронную таблицу Excel
Выходная электронная таблица должна выглядеть примерно так, как показано ниже. Как видите, столбцы с более длинными именами обрезаются, а таблица в целом выглядит ужасно. Проблема была бы еще больше, если бы вам пришлось иметь дело с большим количеством таких столбцов.

Вывести `pandas DataFrame` в электронную таблицу Excel
В следующих разделах мы рассмотрим несколько возможных способов автоматической регулировки ширины столбцов, чтобы итоговая таблица в электронной таблице была более читаемой.
Динамически настраивайте ширину всех столбцов
Чтобы автоматически регулировать ширину столбцов в зависимости от их длины, нам просто нужно выполнить итерацию по столбцам и соответственно установить ширину столбца, как показано ниже:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file.xlsx') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_analysis', index=False, na_rep='NaN')

# Auto-adjust columns' width
for column in df:
    column_width = max(df[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
    col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(column)
    writer.sheets['my_analysis'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)

writer.save()
```

**Примечание.** Если приведенный ниже фрагмент не соответствует следующему AttributeError, перейдите в конец статьи, чтобы узнать, как можно быстро решить эту проблему.

```
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_column'
```

Теперь выходной фрейм данных pandas в электронной таблице Excel стал более читаемым и определенно выглядит лучше. Все столбцы настроены на соответствующую ширину, чтобы они вписывались в пространство без обрезки.

Вывести pandas DataFrame в электронную таблицу Excel с автоматически настраиваемой шириной столбцов
Отрегулируйте ширину столбца, используя его имя
Теперь есть шанс, что вы захотите вручную настроить ширину только для определенного столбца (или подмножества столбцов). Вы можете сделать это, указав имя столбца, как показано во фрагменте ниже. Для этого примера предположим, что мы хотим настроить ширину столбца `this_is_a_long_column_name` на 30:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file.xlsx') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_analysis', index=False, na_rep='NaN')

# Manually adjust the width of the last column
writer.sheets['my_analysis'].set_column(3, 3, 45)

writer.save()
```

Ручная настройка ширины определенного столбца путем ссылки на его имя
Результат приведенного выше фрагмента показан ниже. Как мы видим, ширина столбца `this_is_a_long_column_name` была скорректирована 20, а ширина оставшихся столбцов была скорректирована до значения по умолчанию, что позволяет обрезать столбцы с большей шириной (например, последний).

Выходная таблица с вручную настроенной шириной столбца для this_is_a_long_column_name
Отрегулируйте ширину столбца с помощью его индекса
В качестве альтернативы вы можете вручную настроить ширину определенного столбца, напрямую ссылаясь на его индекс. В примере, показанном ниже, мы демонстрируем это, регулируя ширину последнего столбца.

Ручная настройка ширины определенного столбца путем ссылки на его индекс
Опять же, мы видим, что в этом случае последний столбец был настроен `width=40` так, чтобы он был достаточно широким, чтобы соответствовать имени столбца.

Выходная таблица с вручную настроенной шириной последнего столбца
Как исправить `AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_column'`
В случае сбоя любой из вышеуказанных операций с ошибкой, показанной ниже

```
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_column'
```

все, что вам нужно сделать, это установить `xlswriter`:

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

### Заключение

В этой статье мы исследуем несколько возможных способов автоматической регулировки ширины столбцов при записи pandas DataFrame в электронные таблицы Excel. Обычно мы создаем электронные таблицы, чтобы генерировать элементы информации, которые выглядят красиво и легко читаются. Поэтому важно создавать электронные таблицы, которые не потребуют от читателя каких-либо ручных усилий, чтобы сделать их удобочитаемыми. Вы можете добиться этого с помощью минимального кода, который я поделился ранее, который определенно поможет вам создавать высококачественные файлы Excel при попытке создать их из pandas DataFrames.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, отмечу этот ответ как подходящий. Но я уже нашла другое решение в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1347139/396307) - `openxlsx`. Раньше я использовала его, но не пыталась делать через него форматирование. Потом наткнулась на `pandas`, мне он показался удобнее, но, после того как столкнулась с множеством проблем при сборке приложений с `pandas`, решила полностью от него отказаться.

Comment: FutureWarning: save is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected results and will be removed in a future version
  writer.save()

Answer (score 1):

Приведённый ниже вариант должен работать:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 120)
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
```

Но пропишите перед этим **import pandas as pd**. Или пропишите **import pandas**, но измените код:

```
pandas.set_option('max_colwidth', 120)
pandas.set_option('display.width', 500)
```

Если и это не помогло, то можете посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas/38075046#38075046).