# Как записать excel файл в нормальном виде на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, форматирование, запись

Как записать `excel` файл на `python` в нормальном для просмотра виде? Чтобы как минимум можно было настроить ширину столбцов и перенос содержимого в случае если оно не вмещается. В идеале конечно с возможностью стилизации и авто-форматированием ширины по содержимому, но просмотрев все возможные варианты в интернете, я поняла, что это что-то из мира фантастики, однозначных ответов нету, а отдельные предложенные фрагменты кода громоздкие и к тому же у меня они не работают. Также в основном все примеры с `pandas`, но как сделать вышеперечисленные пункты на этом самом `pandas` я не нашла, задала [отдельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1341798/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-pandas) со всеми примерами, что я пробовала, уже более 2-х недель ответа нету. Поэтому я хочу спросить, возможно есть альтернативы, где это реально сделать? Как именно это сделать мне не принципиально.

*Это не дубликат вышеуказанного вопроса, он об конкретной проблеме с pandas, а данный вопрос обобщённый, о записи в excel файл на python.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я использую [openxlsx](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/), возможно вам также подойдет это решение, например:

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl.styles.fills import PatternFill

# Загружаем документ
book = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')

# Определяем рабочий лист
ws = book.worksheets[0]

# Определяем необходимую ячейку на листе
_cell = ws['C1']

# Задаем стиль для ячейки
_cell.font = Font(size=10, underline='single', color='FFFFFF', bold=True, italic=True)
_cell.value = 'hello world'

# Задаем цвет фона
_cell.fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type = "solid")

# Указываем ширину для колонки
ws.column_dimensions["C"].width = 60.0

# Сохраняем документ
book.save('foo.xlsx')
```

Может быть полезным: [Работа со стилями в openxlsx](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html)

Comment: я так понимаю записывать проще с помощью `pandas`, а затем через `openpyxl` применять нужные стили? И ещё вопрос, у меня при запуске выходит много ошибок при определении ячейки и стилизации - https://ibb.co/bsscy9p.

Comment: @Афродита обновил код в соответствии с актуальной версией openpyxl, можете пробовать, больше информации по стилям в их официальной документации по ссылке, которую прикладывал)

Comment: спасибо большое